# Do some people use bots and is it allowed?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question, and it got posted twice (I click once, but sometimes my mouse clicks twice), and then immediately downvoted before the post appeared on the feed, and then I deleted the first one because it got duplicated, and there's someone who told me to not ask the same question after deleting it, but obviously it's not true and it seems the person was using a bot to instantly downvote some question. Is using a bot allowed?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't take much of a "bot" for someone to DV two questions on the main page. I assume you didn't post your duplicates hours apart.

As for quick votes... sometimes people do DV a Q as soon as it's posted. I think some people use RSS question feeds and the like. There's probably nothing contrary to CoC in that regard, seeing that the RSS feeds ([e.g](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/6728)) are somewhat prominently advertised by SX itself.

As bots that can write to SX, some apparently exist, or at least an [API for them](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) but I've never seen that used on P.SE. Such posts would appear explicitly marked  so via a comment, but I'm not sure how that would work for votes.

Also consider that you do ask a lot questions here, which makes it more likely that someone would run into your Qs. (You have 16/50 questions currently on main page, which easily puts you at number one right now. The next question asker has 7 Qs on main page.)

Comment: It's most likely a race condition between real world events.  If I was writing a "bot", i.e. a script automating some user interactions, I would almost certainly build in time delays between actions.

Answer (score 1):

People can and do see your posts as soon as they happen and they are able to make decisions on a post in a short time.

Also you shouldn't accuse people of using bots when you have no evidence to support it. The simple fact is that a user can be on one question, make a vote and see that it is quickly deleted. When they go back to the main page they see it again and get the impression that you are deleting posts and reposting based on what they see from timestamps.

It seems strange that you are able to frequently post the same question multiple times.

Also if you are going to delete a question because it was a duplicate post you should at least put a comment or edit on the question stating such before you delete it and point to the other question. Otherwise it can be easy to think that it was deleted because of the downvotes and reposted to avoid them.